# How to parse many cursors into many classes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to call this procedure, but I want to know if is possible to parse all 3 cursors into different classes, for ex:
for cursor 1 getResultList() will return class_1
for cursor 2 getResultList() will return class_2
and etc
If I use the same class as a resultclass everything work as expected, but in some cases, we can have 3 cursors with different layouts.

```
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Budget_Calc.Budget_By_Activity_Type",Curr.class);

        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Project_Id",         Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Primary_Check_Id_I", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Log_Id_I",           Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);

        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Return_Set_Curr",  void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Return_Set_Appr",  void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Return_Set_All",   void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_Execution_Status_O", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

        storedProcedure.setParameter("P_Project_Id", projectId);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("P_Primary_Check_Id_I", P_Primary_Check_Id_I);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("P_Log_Id_I", P_Log_Id_I);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Probably there is no way to do that with JPA, but is very easy to do manually

First, you need to get the ResultSet from the procedure, like this:

```
 ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("P_Return_Set_O");
```

and then parse it into a POJO, It is important to see that I built a map for the column Names because not all fields are mandatory, so this gives you a bit more of flexibility

```
public class EntityParser {

    public static <T> List<T> parseResultSet(ResultSet resultSet, Class<T> entityClass) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String,String>mapColumnName = getMapColumnName(resultSet);

        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

           T t = entityClass.newInstance();

           Field[] fieldClass = entityClass.getDeclaredFields();

           for (Field field: fieldClass){

                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String columnName = field.getAnnotation(Column.class).name();

                    if(mapColumnName.containsKey(columnName.toUpperCase()))
                        field.set(t,resultSet.getObject(columnName,field.getType()));

                }
           }

            list.add(t);

        }
        return list;
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> getMapColumnName(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
        HashMap<String,String>mapColumnName = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String columnName=meta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
            mapColumnName.put(columnName,columnName);
        }

        return mapColumnName;
    }

}
```